# Using EGit with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, egit

I have little confusion using EGit with Eclipse. As i am familiar with TFS, i want to understand following things done in EGit.

1. Getting latest from the remote server

   a. While getting latest, how i can preserve local copy and remote copy.
2. Commit changes to remote server

I am developing Android apps in Eclipse using EGit as a repository. Using EGit in Eclipse UI. Not an user of git command at command line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your question has been answered. Please mark an answer as correct, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perfectly use EGit with Eclipse instead of the console.

I'm assuming your EGit is already properly configured and working.

1. Right click on project > Team > Fetch
2. For this you have to have the remote server configured properly. First you must commit to your local copy (Right click on project > Team > Commit) then push to remote (Right click on project > Team > Push)

Comment: I'd recommend using the _Git Staging_ view for committing, it's easier to open (as it's a view) and you don't have a modal dialog blocking your view on other things. For Fetch/Push I recommend using the Git toolbar: _Window_ -> _Customize Perspective_. Then go to _Command Groups Availability_ and check _Git_.

Answer (score 0):

I use rather console that egit. I found it more reliable. In general you have branches
you can create your own branch (local branch with your changes) and just merge it from time to time with remote (server) branch. This way you can easily switch between your branch and main server branch. To commit changes first of all you have to commit them to your own local branch and then push them to the server. (using console it would be like that git push origin master - where master is the name of the remote branch you are pushing to).

Comment: Not really an answer as you're not answering how to do that through EGit.